# Setting Password for phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, password-protection

I am using rhel 5 and php 5 with mysql 5. My server is already configured and running all applications smoothly. I am accessing mysql as root and password is 'anitha123'. but when i am  accessing phpmyadmin through browser, it is not asking for password. Somebody please tell me how can i set it like prompting for username ans password. Since i am not familiar with php mysql please tell me how to do it in simple way.

Comment: For help managing a server, you should consider posting your questions on http://serverfault.com - Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 7):

find phpmyadmin.conf
and set auth type it to http

```
/* Authentication type */  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

Answer (score 1):

or simply you can add password into the configuration file of phpmyadmin. for this
find config.inc.php file which is in phpmyadmin directory then make these changes

find the line 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = '';

then add your password in blanck field as

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = 'anitha123';

and it always open with the same username and password

Answer (score 1):

Go to phpmyadmin and Make sure you have 3 root user to use mysql smoothly. If you are seeing "No" in Password column set new password by Clicking on `Edit Privileges---> Change Password` select `Password` option and set your password.(All of three must be set to `Password Yes`). While doing this do not refresh you browser other wise you will get an error

```
xampp mysql Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: YES
```

Your users screen must be like this.

```
User name   Host        Password          Global privileges
root      127.0.0.1         Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes     
root      ::1               Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes     
root      localhost         Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes
```

When finish this. Just use this setting-> Open config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;  
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Now open phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin will ask you for password. if you provide correct password,You will be able to login.